# Can we set ADF parameters value or linked Service connection string in Custom TASK

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to dynamically change Connection string in Custom task and then want this to reflect in ADF pipeline? Is there a way I can set the pipeline Parameter value in Custom Code task and make my Connection String Parametrised in ADF pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now supported by data factory, read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/parameterize-linked-services

Always think of the context where it will be running, for example if you reference a pipeline parameter from the linked service you will receive a warning. But if at runtime there is a pipeline that matches what you configured at the linked service, you will have no problems.

Hope this helped!

Comment: This helps us set the connection string with Parameters. Can we SET parameters values in Custom Code Task?